# C++ - no rule to create target SaltPepper.o

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, target

I know there are several questions like this, no answer I have found so far seems to solve my problem.

I am using eclipse.

I coded something in the main function, and it worked fine.
I then an external function with the code in the main and now I get funny mistakes.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
void  createSaltandPepper();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 createSaltandPepper();
 return 0;

}
```

No, as I am trying not to give to extensive an example again, here is the outside of the function:

```
void  createSaltandPepper() {
//mycode
}
```

At least it does not seem to be a spelling mistake.

However, the error is:

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target 'SaltPepper.o', needed by 'Display'.
```

I do wonder why it is trying to make a tagert called SaltPepper.o if my function is called createSaltandPepper.

Can somebody help me?

Edit: I did not conciously create a makefile, as I said I am working with eclipse.
And again, the code works fine as long as it is inside the main function instead of inside createSaltandPepper().
My file is called DisplayImage.cpp, the code above is in this file, including the function createSaltandPepper();
The only two function in this file are the main function and createSaltandPepper();
There are no other source files in the project.

I am sorry if I come across as rather stupid: I am a Java programmer and have not a clue about makefiles and such.

See this screenshot:

[image: myeclipse]

I now created a new project and added my old file into it, this time calling it Display.cpp

"build all" resulted in an error in subdir.mk which reads:

```
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'Display.o' failed
make: *** [Display.o] Error 1
```

The complete Error message for the build is as follows:

```
make all 
Building file: ../Display.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0-std=c++11 -MMD -MP  -MF"Display.d"     -MT"Display.d" -o"Display.o" "../Display.cpp"
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'Display.o' failed
g++: error: argument to ‘-fmessage-length=’ should be a non-negative  integer  
make: *** [Display.o] Error 1
```

**Update**

I switched to Netbeans.
It now works.

Comment: Did you [push it?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCadcBR95oU) You have to push it real good.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. You have a problem with your makefile. Step 1 to learning how to develop with C++: learn to recognize an actual C++ error message from a compiler, versus your build system.

Comment: This is a reason for you to downvote something....
It did bytheway work perfectly fine as long as all the code was in the main function

Comment: Cody Gray, that video is not available in my country

Comment: @user1862770 Sam is right, the error has nothing to do with C++. Even if you didn't create the makefile yourself, you still have one, and you'll have to debug it. Hint: is SaltPepper.c added to your eclipse project?

Comment: I do not have a file with the name SaltandPepper, I only have ONE source file in the project.

Comment: Then what files **do** you have? Don't make people guess. Clearly the function is not defined in `main.cpp` or whatever you've quoted here, so where **is** it defined?

Comment: Where does your `createSaltAndPepper` function reside? In which file?

Comment: I answered your questions in an edit

Comment: @user1862770 Your screenshot looks correct from the first glance. Try creating the project again and then add your existing file.

Comment: Done that @IlyaPopov, see the results in the newest edit.

Comment: @user1862770 Do you see the error is changed? Now it says that the building of Display.o is failed. Most likely there is some syntax error in you cpp file. Above should be the error message from the compiler itself.

Comment: @user1862770 Also see if there is anything in the 'Problems' tab now.

Comment: It seems to have someting to do with c++11 I thought it was enabled. But if it is that, then why did it work with the code in the main function? And no, no syntax errors, really

Comment: @user1862770 If you'd like to continue, please post the **complete** error message to the new separate question. We cannot guess what is your problem without seeing the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this error has nothing to do with compilers, this error message is produced by the build system (`make` in your case). Basically, eclipse seems to call `make`, which figures out what are dependencies between files and which of them need recompiling and in turn calls the compiler to compile them. Every C++ source file is then compiled to an object file `.o` (typically with the same name: `SaltPepper.cpp` -> `SaltPepper.o`). Then all the object files are linked together with the libraries to form the final executable.

This particular error message tells you that your executable is specified to depend on the object file `SaltPepper.o`, but the build system does not know how to produce it. Most likely there is no corresponding `SaltPepper.cpp` file. So check if such file exists. If not, check the settings of your project (or the Makefile if you created it manually) and see if all the cpp filenames are specified correctly. You should add all the cpp files with your code to the project, and remove all the extraneous cpp files.

**Update**: Note that build system operates on the file level. It does not know anything about functions etc., only source files. Maybe this is the source of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you - I did go to project->properties->settings and through all the tabs but did find nothing that looked like it was related to a makefile. can you help me there

Comment: Makefile is probably generated automatically by eclipse. You have to make sure that the the list of cpp files in the 'Project' pane is correct.

Comment: @user1862770 See this screenshot: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-ganymede/fig4.jpg There is a 'Project explorer' pane in the top left. You should see all your cpp files there. If not, find the 'Add file to project' command (or something similar)

Comment: @user1862770 Is it the only cpp file there? Are you 100% sure it has a correct name, and you are actually editing the file with the same name? If yes, then it is strange. I could only recommend you to close everything, create the new empty project and add you source file to the newly created project.